# how to avoid comments while extracting text from web pages in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to extract only **text from web page** but i am facing some problem like texts which are not in written in the page but they are written in code which are comments such as: "include footer", "sidebar.php end" etc. Also the unwanted things are also coming which i really do not want. Here are the links which i am using for test case i.e:

1) http://ai-depot.com/articles/the-easy-way-to-extract-useful-text-from-arbitrary-html

2) http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/index.htm

3) http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/program_structure/

(so that i can ensure my code is extracting text from any page)

here is the code which i am facing trouble:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "http://ai-depot.com/articles/the-easy-way-to-extract-useful-text-from-arbitrary-html/" 
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for script in soup(["script", "style","a","p","li","<!-->","small","<div id=\"footer\">","<div id=\"footer\">","<div id=\"bottom\">"]):
    script.extract()    

text = soup.findAll(text=True)
for p in text:
    print unicode(p)
fo = open('file.txt', 'w')
fo.seek(0, 2)
fo.writelines( unicode(p) )
fo.close()
```

in this code i have used number 1 link and when i did **"inspect element"** on that page i found so many comments in that code and this code is extracting them as well. So help please.....

Comment: Your first link is an article that specifically addresses one way to reduce the number of comments when scraping websites.

Comment: so what should i do now? i am new in pyhton.

Comment: Read... a LOT. That's how everyone here who knows anything learned what they know. It might take months or years to gain the necessary skills and information to accomplish your goal, but it's a valuable journey and you'll pick up a lot of other skills along the way.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use a regex to strip/skip comments when your code encounters a line that the regex matches as a comment.

Alternatively, you might be able to use an HTML parser as well.
Python has one built into its standard library.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html